# What is the risk of auto-appending mysql_close & session_write_close to all PHP scripts?

Tags: php

What is the risk of using php's `auto_append_file` to automatically add:

> session_write_close();
>   mysql_close();

To all files?

In working with a customer's application, I found that sessions and database connections were hanging open for some reason.  As a quick fix, we added the code above via the `auto_append_file`.

This immediately resolved the issue of Apache threads staying in the Sending Reply state and reduced server loads considerably.

We are considering using this technique more often when the customer lacks sufficient resources or time to find the problematic code and fix it.

**Edit**

The question is not about best practices. I fully understand that this *should* not be required but I can reproducibly show the a reduction of hung Apache processes with this code added.  The question is about the risk or negative impact would such functions cause.

Comment: The question is not what is the risk, but what is the point? Are you 100% sure this is what you _need_? I'm not. MySQL connections ARE closed automatically anyway. Session is only not write/close-d, if you header redirect...

Comment: I am not a PHP programmer so I am not sure what is required. We handle the operations side.  However, I know that as soon as we add this code the issue of Apache being stuck in Sending Reply resolves.

Comment: this shouldn't solve *anything*. check/update your configuration, try to figure out what really causes the problem and fix *that*.

Comment: I am well aware that it *should* not solve anything .. but it helps tremendously. During peak traffic (300-400 req/sec) the number of Apache processes stuck in Sending Reply drops by 80%.  I think it has to do with session locks not being cleared properly.   Note I am the ops manager not the developers.  The developers do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the driver should close the connection and the session is written and closed at the end of the script's execution anyway.

Also, you should be using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or PDO, not mysql! ([MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php))

Anyway, a better idea when you want to do that kind of thing (execute something right at the end of the script) would be to register a shutdown function to do it ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

(And an even better one is to keep track of whatever resources you are using and release them right at the point where you know your program will not be needing them any more. It's more efficient, and leaves no doubt about what's happening with them.)

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#refsect1-function.session-write-close-description) for `session_write_close()`:

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated *without the need to call session_write_close()*, but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time.

And from [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php#refsect1-function.mysql-close-description) for `mysql_close()`:

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as *non-persistent open links are automatically closed* at the end of the script's execution. See also [freeing resources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct).

Also worth noting from `mysql_close()`, using no link identifier...

> If the link identifier is not specified, the *last link opened* by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

---

**Keeping all of the above in mind:**

1. Calling the above functions *shouldn't be necessary* as they're automatically handled when a script terminates.
2. Calling `mysql_close()` in a script will only a) close the most recently opened link or b) throw a warning because no links were ever opened.
3. If you need scripts to give up resources as soon as they're done with them, using `auto_append_file` won't help you because of point #1.  You'll need to modify the scripts themselves.
4. Database connections hanging open is a sign of a hung or long-running script.  If the script terminated, then the database link should have as well.  (Again, point #1)